# cocos2d iOS - Detect collision with CCDrawNode border

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

I have a CCDrawNode which draws a border on screen.
My sprite are created inside this border, (the border has no fill colour).
Something like this

```
     Border
 ______________
|              | 
|   Sprite     | B
|              | o
|              | r
|      Sprite  | d
|              | e
|              | r
|              |
|           Spr|ite {-- Collision I want to achieve
|______________|
```

I want to detect when the sprites collide with my border.
When I try using `CGRectIntersectsRect` it returns `TRUE` only when
all 4 sprite edges collide with the border.

This is how I check collision

```
- (BOOL)isCollidingWithEdges:(CCNode *)node
{

    for (CCDrawNode *edge in _edgesArray)
    {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect([edge boundingBox], [node boundingBox]))
        {
            NSLog(@"edge collision!!!");
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

and defining an edge

```
    CGPoint verts[4] =
    {
        ccp(0.0f, 0.0f),
        ccp(0.0f, height),
        ccp(width, height),
        ccp(width, 0.0f)
    };

    CCDrawNode *edge = [CCDrawNode node];
    edge.anchorPoint = ccp(0.0f, 0.0f);
    edge.position = ccp(0.0f, 0.0f);
    [edge drawPolyWithVerts:verts count:4 fillColor:fillColor borderWidth:0.0f borderColor:borderColor];
    [self addChild:edge];
    [_edgesArray addObject:edge];
```

I would appreciate any help with that
Thanks!

Comment: show us your code, sounds like you set it up incorrectly (ie ANDing all 4 tests together)

Comment: I think I found the problem, the 'CCDrawNode' width and height are always {0, 0}, what causes that and how can I get it's real width and height?